# How to display a variable with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted if I can do like a create_variable to display a variable with Tkinter.

```
player_score = 0
score = Canvas(window_game, width=300, height=40, bg="black")
score.create_text(50, 20, text="SCORE :", fill="white", font=('Courrier'))
score.grid(row=0,column=0)   #x  #y
lives = Canvas(window_game, width=300, height=40, bg="black")
lives.create_text(50, 20, text="LIVES :", fill="white", font=('Courrier'))
lives.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Hello i wanted to know how to display the variable "payer_score" next to the "SCORE".
Thanks.

Comment: Could you add an example of expected input -> output?

Comment: You will probably fare better embedding a label into your canvas for this. Otherwise you will have to keep deleting and recreating the text every time the score changes. However, to answer your question in the most basic sense ~ use fstrings: `f'SCORE: {player_score}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the canvas `itemconfig` method. First you need make a reference to the canvas item. This is the return value of `create_text` and I've assigned it to `score_text`.

```
score_text = score.create_text(50, 20, text="SCORE :", fill="white", font=('Courrier'))
```

This can then be used to update the text

```
score.itemconfig(score_text, text = "SCORE : " + str(player_score))
```

You will have to do this every time you want the text to change, it will not change automatically when `player_score` changes.